# Use attr_encrypted with key supplied by the customer (Not stored in the database)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using [attr_encrypted](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted) to support encryption of customer data in my rails application. The gem is working when the key is static but when I try to use proc to take key in the controller from `params[:key]` (So that I do not need to store the key), the key is not used correctly. My current code is :

Customer model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  attr_encrypted :phone, key: proc { |key| "#{key}" } , :attribute => 'phone_number'
```

Customer Controller:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    if params[:customer][:phone_number].present?
      @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
      @customer.store_id = @store.id
      key = params[:key]
      @customer.phone = params[:customer][:phone_number]
      @customer.phone_number
      if @customer.save
        return_response['new_customer']=1
      else
        render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
```

The gem says that I can also pass a class method as key. Does someone has any idea about how I can use it to achieve the purpose of not storing the key in the database? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can either specify a custom method or a proc in order to fetch a key dynamically. Both assume the `key` is available in the scope of the current user.

One possible approach is to define a new instance variable in the customer for the key

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor  :encryption_key
```

and instruct the gem to use it as a key.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor  :encryption_key
  attr_encrypted :phone, key: :encryption_key, :attribute => 'phone_number'
```

Now you just need to be sure to set the instance variable before executing the encryption. You can set the key immediately after you created the customer

```
@customer.encryption_key = params[:key]
```

or pass the attribute in the call to `new`.